# Python marshmallow blob/bytes field

Tags: python, python-3.x, odm, marshmallow

I've been searching for a while about how to validate if a dictionary's key has value (required) and this value's type is `bytes` using [Marshmallow](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#), but I didn't find anything that could work.

There's no "basic" field type in the Marshmallow reference documentaiton which matches with `bytes` data type. So I asume that it has to be a custom field.

Does anyone has already faced this problem? Any clue to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: @cricket_007 i've just posted the answer, sorry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well... the solution was quite easy, just reading the correct docs page I figured out how to solve my problem.

Just create a new class which extends from `fields. Field` and override the `_validate` method as follows:

```
class BytesField(fields.Field):
    def _validate(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, bytes):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid input type.')

        if value is None or value == b'':
            raise ValidationError('Invalid value')
```

And here's the marshmallow schema:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    // ...
    field = BytesField(required=True)
    // ...
```

That's all. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Well, it was helpful to me. Thanks. Btw I think `isinstance(value, bytes)` would be better than `type(value) is not bytes`

Comment: wasting your* time

Comment: Please, add a reference to the docs page you used.